# how to achieve selective display in a gridview without taking space

Tags: android

what is the best way to suppress certain entries of an array from getting displayed in a grid view.

I have a dummy entry in an array I'm setting up for display in a grid view. Is there someway to selectively suppress an entry in  get View? i don't want this entry to take up any space in the display. Appreciate the help.

I don't want to make a copy of the array and  i need this dummy entry for display in a different view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in the gridview are taken from an ArrayAdapter. If you mean that you want to ignore certain entries in this adapter and display the rest - the short answer would be no. As an alternative, you could create an adapter which only contains the values that you need and then another one which only contains the dummy values and then bind these adapters as and how you want. In this way, you could just use the same main array.

Comment: thanks. the entries are in an arraylist, im allowing add to this list in this view. Do you know of any convenient sublist function which i can use to create this adapter?

Comment: I'm guessing you are taking only the entries you need based on some particular criterion. Although not fuzzy, you could create a convenience method that would select the entries based on this criterion and put them in a new list. Although this is not very intuitive, this seems to be the best that I can think of for right now.

Comment: There's nothing that is readily available if that's what you mean since you need to give the criterion.

Comment: Hmm my problem is, in View1 i display (dummy entry+ArrayList A), in View 2 I display (ArrayList A). I add and delete entries to ArrayList A in View 2 so my View1's combo cannot be a copy of ArrayList A. I need to find either an ArrayList combine or substring that is not doing a copy of the entries. In view1 im using a custom gridview thing ,im unable to add a new imageview entry to it which is why i have this dummy entry workaround.